# How can I produce horizontal, ascii git history log representations?

Tags: git, ascii

In many StackOverflow questions about git (and in the git man pages themselves), history logs are rendered with ASCII like this

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

While they are not a complete history log representation (for example, they use letters rather than hash codes), I find that they are very useful while talking about merge, rebasing and other topics, especially in emails.

AFAIK, git log can produce very pretty, **vertical**, history log representation like

[image]

Yet I think those serves other goals.

How could I produce **horizontal**, ascii git history logs, using git (and eventually other tools)?

Comment: I don't think it's very realistic to have a horizontal representation.  By the time you have an 7-character SHA and a dash or two in between, you could only fit 9 or 10 commits across horizontally.   And that's with the SHA and absolutely no description.  Commit "5fc86dd" with no description is practically meaningless to me.

Comment: You are right: horizontal representation aren't very realistic. Yet, they are very useful while writing documentation. The official man pages themselves use them. I'm looking for a way to quickly generate them programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Git doesn't come with anything that will show you a horizontal log. I googled "git log horizontal" and didn't find anything on the first page. Maybe someone can write a plugin that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a native bash one-liner that prints git log in the way described which is why I'm searching for it again.

It DOES EXIST! But apparently it's not popular, and I can't find it :/

Comment: Should you stumble upon it again, please, update your comment! That would be very appreciated!